# Haskell Install Mac Failed

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc

This is my first time downloading the `Haskell Platform` on my `Mac OS X 10.8.5`

I downloaded the `Haskell Platform` for `Mac OS X is 7.10.3` I ran it, but it says:

> There are older versions of GHC and/or Haskell Platform on this
>   system. Run the command line tool uninstall-hs to find out which and
>   how to remove them.

So I did `uninstall-hs`, but it says:

> Failed. Reason: EroorMissingBundle.

I've also tried

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/HaskellPlatform.framework
sudo rm -rf /Library/Haskell
rm -rf ~/.cabal
rm -rf ~/.ghc
rm -rf ~/Library/Haskell
find /usr/bin /usr/local/bin -type l | \
  xargs -If sh -c '/bin/echo -n f /; readlink f' | \
  egrep '//Library/(Haskell|Frameworks/(GHC|HaskellPlatform).framework)' | \
  cut -f 1 -d ' ' > /tmp/hs-bin-links
sudo rm -f `cat /tmp/hs-bin-links`
```

But I am still getting the same results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a bit orthogonal to the question, but why not give stack (http://docs.haskellstack.org) a try?

Comment: I agree with angerman - while the Platform did solve real problems in the past it sometimes create many more - just go with stack or [Haskell for Mac](https://ghcformacosx.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

It does no harm to leave the older versions around.

The missing bundle stuff looks like it may have to do with new mac security features by the way.

To find out what the commands to run by hand are, you can run `uninstall-hs only VERSION --script` and that may work.